# Riemann Integrable Question

Tags: riemann-integration

Hi I am confused about the following question. I am trying to understand the conditions for when the rationals intersect the closed interval. I know that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ but don't fully grasp how the function is set up.

> Let $f \colon[a,b] \to \mathbb{R}$ be defined by
>   $$ f(x) = \begin{cases} 1,& x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap [a,b] \\ -1,& x \in \mathbb{Q}^c \cap [a,b]\end{cases}$$
>   Determine whether $f$ is Riemann integrable on $[a,b]$.

Comment: The rationals are not just a subset; they are a *dense* subset.  Every interval contains both rational numbers and irrational numbers.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The interval $[a,b]$ is the set of all real numbers which are greater than or equal ot $a$ and less than or equal to $b$

Most of these real numbers are irrational and the other ones are rational.

One very important fact is that both rationals and irrationals are dense in the interval $[a,b]$ meaning that no matter how small a non-empty  open  interval you choose  inside $[a,b]$ there are both rationals and irrationals in it.

The way your function is defined for every closed interval  you get the  least upper bound of $1$ and the greatest lower bound of $-1$

You can take it from here.